# I need help making a program to tell if the shape you input is a parallelogram

Tags: python

I'm trying to make the a and b equal the same and when a and b are the same, c and d have to be the same, but they can be different from a and b

```
play = True

while play:

a = float(input("Enter length of side A: "))
b = float(input("Enter length of side B: "))
c = float(input("Enter length of side C: "))
d = float(input("Enter length of side D: "))

if 'a' == 'b' and 'c' == 'd':
    print("It's a parallelogram")

elif 'a' == 'c' and 'b' == 'd':
    print("It's a parallelogram")
elif 'b' == 'c' and 'a' == 'd':
    print("It's a parallelogram")
else:
    print("It is not a parallelogram")
    continue
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Also, `'a' == 'b'` is comparing the literal string "a" and literal string "b" to each other, which is always going to be False. You want `if a == b`

Comment: it keep saying it's not a parallelogram when it is.

Comment: Nvm it doesn't work even if all the sides are the same xD

Comment: Could you update your question to state your problem? Also, see my comment regarding if statements.

Comment: But 'a==b and c==d' is NOT a parallelogram a,b,c,d

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your logic to sth like the following and not use the string literals `'a', 'b'`, etc. but the actual variable names:

```
a, b, c, d = sorted(
    float(input("Enter length of side {}: ".format(x))) for x in 'ABCD'
)  
if a == b and c == d:
    # parallel
```

Comment: using that instead of having 'a = float(input("Enter length of side A: ") ' or would I keep that?

Comment: You keep that in order to get those values.

Comment: @NickDamore I updated the answer and DRYed the input reading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare variables, with variables, not strings:

```
play = True

while play:

    a = float(input("Enter length of side A: "))
    b = float(input("Enter length of side B: "))
    c = float(input("Enter length of side C: "))
    d = float(input("Enter length of side D: "))

    if a == b and c == d:
        print("It's a parallelogram")

    elif a == c and b == d:
        print("It's a parallelogram")
    elif b == c and a == d:
        print("It's a parallelogram")
    else:
        print("It is not a parallelogram")
```

You could simplify the tests further, and extract the i/o in a function:

```
def get_values():
    a = float(input("Enter length of side A: "))
    b = float(input("Enter length of side B: "))
    c = float(input("Enter length of side C: "))
    d = float(input("Enter length of side D: "))

    return a, b, c, d

play = True
while play:

    a, b, c, d = get_values()
    if (a == b and c == d) or (a == c and b == d) or (b == c and a == d):
        print("It's a parallelogram")
    else:
        print("It is not a parallelogram")
```

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't think of making a function

Comment: That's okay, after a while, it becomes a habit to isolate and restrict i/o to a handful of classes and functions.